Where can I contribute to data science projects/research as a student?
I'm a master's student in DS, and someone recommended to me that I could fill out my resume by contributing to "open source data science projects". But after looking around for these, I'm starting to think they aren't what I thought they were. I was expecting projects where someone had a lot of data to clean and build models off of, so they would be looking for people like me to help. Instead, every "open source data science project" I can find seems to be about developing some software or library that gets used for data science, rather than me doing DS myself. I have very little experience with software development, and even if I did, every project I see on Github goes way over my head, so I wouldn't even know what to contribute.
So is there such a thing as an open source project where I could help people clean and analyze their data? Where would I look to find that?
(I should clarify that I'm already on Kaggle, but what I'm looking for are ways to build my resume by contributing to actual projects. As far as I can tell, Kaggle competitions are just for practice and won't do much for a resume.)
